# Flask does not load css file with query string

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have started to work on flask, and the problem is i have created a css file in static folder and wanted to load that css file on template.

but it is not loading css file even if i try this on incognito mode i thought it could be a cache problem but it does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Welcome to My Blog</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="=text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css?v=0.01') }}">

<h2>Hey there {{ name }}</h2>
```

[Image :Hello world flask app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IwuN.png)

Blog.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


...
@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def profile(username):
    return render_template("profile.html", name=username)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

style.css

```
h2{
    color: #00bfff;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you include the query string in your filename.

```
url_for('static', filename='style.css?v=0.01')
```

The url path results in `static/style.css%3Fv%3D0.01`, because the special characters get encoded. To fix this you must add query elements as keyword arguments:

```
url_for('static', filename='style.css', v=0.01)
```

Additionally:

- Your file is called `stye.css` and not `style.css`
- Your `<link>` tag says `type="=text/css"` and not `type="text/css"` as it should

Comment: i have changed it but still its the same.

Comment: when i try to open; http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/style.css?v=0.01
i get a not found error.

Comment: i have renamed and rerun but still getting error. i have added style.css file on question.

Comment: sorry i meant color is still black.

Comment: thank you, i got my lesson, should be more carefull about typo and control every letter before asking question :).

Comment: You're welcome! To be honest I was a bit surprised Chrome didn't catch the typo and ignore it. :)

Comment: I dont understand why people dont vote up when someone actually answers something..

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, Sometimes encoding itself causes the problems. Make sure you have right encoding.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Include charset attribute in your HTML file. Also, to avoid using cached responses of your browser, try refreshing your content using **ctrl + F5** keys.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added following line to my code and it worked

```
app.static_folder = 'static'
```

and you have to change the

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="=text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css?v=0.01') }}">`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"/>`